# Converting Invariable plane to J2000 ecliptic

Tags: planet, coordinate, rotation, pole

I've been following the answer given by Mike G here: [How to calculate the orientation of planets at current epoch](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/how-to-calculate-the-orientation-of-planets-at-current-epoch/32328) to get planets to have the correct orientation in my program, but all the angles are in the Invariable plane, how is that converted to the J2000 ecliptic plane? I've been stuck at this for hours and it makes my head hurt, any help would very much be appreciated!

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to give us more details? For instance, are you developing an app (as in the linked question)? Are you using the approach set out in [Mike G's answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/32328/14094)? Was the [OP's comment to that answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/how-to-calculate-the-orientation-of-planets-at-current-epoch/32328#comment59411_32328) useful? The more you can tell us about what you're trying to do, the more likely someone will be able to post the solution you're after.

Comment: This should help: Algorithm for I.A.U. North Poles and Rotation Parameters - which way is up? http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1993CeMDA..57..473L